# Combining hazard ratios

Tags: hazard, risk

I was wondering if someone could help me with a doubt about hazard ratios (HR). I have access to a publication reporting HR of death given exposure A obtained through Cox regression. Reported HRs are stratified by sex (for males or females) and by age categories. What I would like to have is age and gender-specific HRs (i.e. HR for a 50-year-old female). Can the HRs simply be multiplied to obtain the desired hazards? Using the sample data below: HR = 1.446*1879 = 2.717.
Thank you
[image]

Comment: These cannot be hazard *ratios* because there is no referent group. A ratio is a contrast, i.e. a comparison between two groups, but you seem to have a covariate value for each age group and each sex. Are these values not HRs but incidence rates instead?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I should have clarified that the comparison is the group without exposure to A. The HR of death in females exposed is 1.446 compared to females not exposed to A.

Comment: Even so, this is somehow not a complete picture. A "referent" group in such an analysis might be unexposed females age <50. But the presence of covariate in "exposure to A" column suggests that either these are interaction terms from separate or joint model(s), or they are in fact incidence rates in the exposed arm as previously mentioned. If they are interaction terms, you still can't get after the value you want because you lack knowledge of the lower level effects, i.e. the marginal effects of age, sex irrespective of exposure.

Comment: Thank you for persisting with this. I have clearly not provided sufficient information. I have replaced the original table so that it provides more detail.